# Sequence of Independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, limsup-and-liminf, independence, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Suppose $\{X_n, n \geq 1\}$ are independent random variables. Show
$$P[\sup_{n} X_n < \infty]=1$$
iff
$$\sum_{n}P[X_n > M]< \infty 
\text{ for some }M.$$
**Proof so far:**
$\Longleftarrow$ If $\sum_{n}P[X_n > M]< \infty$ for some $M$, then
$P\{[X_n > M] \text{ i.o}\}=0$. So
$$P \{\liminf[X_n \leq M]\}=1-P \{\limsup[X_n > M]\}=1$$
So we have a sequence of $X_{n},X_{n+1},....$ all less than or equal to $M$. So the intersection of such sets would be the $ \sup_{k\geq n} X_k \leq M <\infty$. Hence $P[\sup_{n} X_n < \infty]=1$

Comment: I am so lost. Can anyone provides some hints.

Comment: The same works in the opposite direction (via the inverse Borel-Cantelli).

Comment: is what I have so far correct @zhoraster

Comment: Well, this is correct (although you could add a couple of words explaining the last conclusion).

Comment: I don't know exactly know how to get to the conclusion @zhoraster

Comment: Don't you? If $\sup_{k\ge n} X_k <\infty$, then $\sup_{k\ge 1} X_k<\infty$. You don't know why, really?

Comment: Yea I understand @zhoraster Thanks for your help

Comment: Oops. You've adding something absurd...

Comment: @zhoraster Why? What if $X_1 = \infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I think the proof below allows the random variables to take values in $(\overline{\mathbb R}, \mathscr B(\overline{\mathbb R}))$, in w/c case @zhoraster's [claim](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457607/sequence-of-independent-random-variables/1547966#comment2968225_1457607) may not hold.

If anything below assumes the random variables take values only in $(\mathbb R, \mathscr B(\mathbb R))$, pls point it out.

---

'if'

Let $A_n^c := \{X_n > M\}$. By BCL1, we have

$$P(\limsup A_n^C) = 0$$

$$\to P(\liminf A_n) = 1$$

$$\to P(\lim A_n) = 1$$

$$\to \lim P(A_n) = 1$$

$$\to P(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n) = 1$$

$$\to \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_n) = 1 \ \text{Why?}$$

$$\to \forall n \in \mathbb N, P(A_n) = 1$$

$$\to \forall n \in \mathbb N, P\{X_n \le M\} = 1$$

$$\to P( \sup_{n \ge 1} (X_n) < \infty) = 1$$

'only if'

Show the contrapositive:

By BCL2, we have

$$P(\limsup A_n^C) = 1 \ (\forall M > 0)$$

$$\to P(\liminf A_n) = 0$$

$$\to \lim_{m \to \infty} P(\bigcap_{n=m}^{\infty} A_n) = 0$$

$$\to \lim_{m \to \infty} \prod_{n=m}^{\infty} P(A_n) = 0$$

$$\to \sup_{m \ge 1} \prod_{n=m}^{\infty} P(A_n) = 0$$

$\to \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists, m \ge 1$ s.t.

$$\prod_{n=m}^{\infty} P(A_n) = 0$$

$\exists n \ge m$ s.t. $P(A_n) = 0$

$$\to P(X_n \le M) = 0 \tag{*}$$

Now suppose on the contrary that $P[\sup X_n < \infty] = 1$.

$$\to \sup[X_1, X_2, ...] < \infty \ \text{a.s.}$$

$\to \exists N \ge 0$ s.t.

$$P(\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} X_n \le N ) = 1$$

$$\to \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X_n \le N ) = 1$$

$$\to P(X_n \le N ) = 1 \forall n \ge 1$$

Choose $M = N$ in $(*)$. ↯

$$\therefore, \forall M > 0, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(X_n > M) =\infty \to P[\sup X_n < \infty] < 1$$

QED