# Does $\sup_{n \ge m} Y_n < \infty \ \text{a.s.}$ imply $\sup_{n \ge 1} Y_n < \infty \ \text{a.s. ?}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables, supremum-and-infimum, independence

> Suppose $Y_1, Y_2, ...$ are independent random variables and $\exists m \ge 1$ s.t.
>
> $$\sup_{n \ge m} Y_n < \infty \ \text{a.s.}$$
>
> Does this mean
>
> $$\sup_{n \ge 1} Y_n < \infty \ \text{a.s. ?}$$

I was thinking say $m = 2$ and $Y_1 = \infty$, then $\sup_{n \ge m} Y_n < \infty$, but $\sup_{n \ge 1} Y_n = \infty ?$

I have a feeling either the independence or the 'a.s.' is needed here.

My guess is that $\sup_{n \ge 1} Y_n = \infty $ but $\sup_{n \ge 1} Y_n < \infty \ \text{a.s. ?}$

Comment: Where do the $Y_n$s take their values?

Comment: @JohnDawkins $(\overline{\mathbb R}, \mathscr B (\overline{\mathbb R}))$, I guess. If $(\mathbb R, \mathscr B (\mathbb R))$, the result holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $(\sup\limits_n Y_n)(x)=\sup\limits_{n}\{Y_n(x)\}$ then indeed, there is nothing guaranteeing that the first random variable $Y_1$ should be finite a.s and therefore there is no reason that your claim should be true in general. The example you posited disproves it, but you need to fix values for all the later $Y_n$ as well (i.e. with $n\geq2$). For example, setting $Y_n=0$ whenever $n\geq2$, would do the trick.

On the other hand, if the $Y_n$ were an **increasing** sequence  of random variables, then the result would be true.

Comment: Supremum is taken over n not x

Comment: Yes, but then what value is the sup referring to? The largest value taken by any of the random variables? In what sense do you mean to take the "largest" $Y_n$? For example, what would be the supremum of $Y_1$ which is zero on $\lbrack -\infty,0\rbrack$ and 1 elsewhere, and $Y_2$ which is 1 on $\lbrack -\infty,0\rbrack$ and zero else?

Comment: I've altered my answer slightly to better reflect the meaning of the $\sup$ notation I'm using. Hopefully it helps make things clearer.

Comment: Sup Yn is a random variable right?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: Why do I need to fix values? As long as Y1 is infinity, who cares?

Comment: Also sup <> max :p

Comment: Well, it's not so much that you need to fix the $Y_n$ to have a particular value, but you certainly need to make sure that they are eventually finite, i.e. that there is an $m$ so that when $n>m$, $\sup\{Y_n(x)\}<\infty$ right? 

Consider the sequence $Y_n=\infty$ for every $n$. This doesn't provide the counterexample we seek, but by your logic, since $Y_1=\infty$ it should be fine.

Comment: But that doesn't use the assumption of eventual finiteness, does it? :|

Comment: Oh, of course you are correct, and this is why the $Y_n$ need to be specified! Because if we don't we can construct examples which satisfy everything we wanted except for eventual finiteness, and are therefore not valid as counterexamples.

The point is I've given you an example where $Y_1=\infty$. You have asked why this isn't "good enough", and the reason is because the example I gave is not valid - it doesn't satisfy the question's assumptions! So more needs to be said about the $Y_n$ than simply $Y_1=\infty$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32202/discussion-between-luke-hamblin-and-bclc).

Comment: It's like this if we have Y1 = infinity and the Yns satisfy the assumptions, then we have our counterexample right?

Comment: Luke Hamblin, if the random variables take values in $(\mathbb R, \mathscr B(\mathbb R))$, does the result hold?

Comment: Does [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457607/sequence-of-independent-random-variables/1547966#comment2968225_1457607) make use of other assumptions?

Answer (score 2):

> I was thinking say $m = 2$ and $Y_1 = \infty$, then $\sup_{n \ge m} Y_n < \infty$, but $\sup_{n \ge 1} Y_n = \infty ?$

You almost answered you own question. You need further assumption for $Y_n$ with $n\geq 2$ though. Say, $Y_n\equiv 1$ for each $n$. Then the $Y_n$'s are independent. (Why?) Then you can check that the quoted statement is not true.

Comment: Jack, I don't get it. if $Y_1 = \infty$, how can $sup_{n \ge 1} Y_n < \infty$? That seems to be what you are suggesting

Comment: I think Jack is saying to take $Y_1=\infty$, then $Y_n\equiv 1$ for every $n\geq2$. This then means that $\sup\limits_{n\geq1}Y_n=\infty$, but $\sup\limits_{n\geq2}Y_n=1<\infty$, disproving the claim.

Comment: Jack and @LukeHamblin Reread answer. Thanks why are further assumptions needed? To make sure they are independent?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, exactly. You need to ensure that the example you give is both eventually finite and made of independent random variables, otherwise its not a counterexample to the claim (it fails the assumptions).

Comment: Jack and. @LukeHamblin  It's like this if we have Y1 = infinity and the Yns satisfy the assumptions, then we have our counterexample right?

Comment: @BCLC Yes that's right. :)

Comment: Jack and @LukeHamblin, if the random variables take values in $(\mathbb R, \mathscr B(\mathbb R))$, does the result hold?

Comment: Does [this comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457607/sequence-of-independent-random-variables/1547966#comment2968225_1457607) make use of other assumptions?

Comment: @BCLC Yes the result holds if the random variables take values in $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. I believe this is what the comment is assuming on the other question.